# Get FusedLocationProviderClient BroadcastReceiver to restart on boot completed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent, fusedlocationproviderapi, google-location-services

I've managed to implement background location updates using FusedLocationProviderClient PendingIntent and BroadcastReceiver inside my MainActivity class but when I restart my phone I am unable to get it triggering again.

I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

and

```
<receiver
   android:name=".LocationBroadcastReceiver"
   android:exported="true"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:permission="com.x.location.LOC_PERMISSION">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.x.location.LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_UPDATE" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

already and with this it did trigger my LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver:

```
if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
    // Can see it coming through here then I
    // request location updates - see code below
}
```

but when I try to request location updates again it just doesn't do anything. This is pretty much the code I used to request location updates again:

```
private void requestLocationUpdates(Context context) {
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);

    LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
    long millis = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    request.setInterval(millis);
    request.setFastestInterval(millis);
    request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    request.setMaxWaitTime(millis);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, LocationBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(LocationBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_DISTANCE_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(request, pi);
   }
```

I tried the code above both in the LocationUpdatesBroadcastReceiver and also by starting a service too but still no luck.

Also tried changing the request code to a different number so it does not clash with the first one I used inside MainActivity and/or changed the flag to PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT as well but still the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I am experiencing exact same symptoms.